# Getting asynchronous script timeout while using ngwebdriver with selenium for automating angular5 application

Tags: selenium, angular5

I'm using below code

```
ngDriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) driver());
ngDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```

and below error I'm getting

> INFO: toggle button is not clicked asynchronous script timeout: result
>   was not received in 30 seconds   (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103) 
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470
>   (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT